# Microsoft Translation API - Bing Translator Response

Tags: azure, bing, microsoft-translator

I am using the Microsoft Translation API to translate mostly single words. I use the API function GetTranslations as follows:

https://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Http.svc/GetTranslations?text=building&from=es&to=de&maxTranslations=50

and I get a list of words with a match score (0 - 100). This result differs a lot from what it is normally seen in Bing Translator online where one can get for a word Nouns and Verbs and several alternative translations. Is there any way to get the same Response as in Bing using the Translation API?